# What do I implement to add a new OS to Docker?

Tags: docker

If I want to add something like FreeDOS or Darwin support to Docker what do I need to implement ?

I can't find any info on how the commands in the Dockerfile are actually run and translated into commands to create new layers in the storage backend.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby is the core userspace Docker implementation, but there's also substantial Linux kernel support.  This is not at all a small task.

Comment: Is there any info about how RUN echo hello world gets to be run in the container ?

Comment: Internally it should be the equivalent of `docker run` and then `docker commit`, but the actual mechanics of how that "run" action happens (including especially how the container filesystem is established) are pretty complex.  You can't "just" port this to another OS easily.

Comment: I guess for DOSEMU inside a Linux inside Docker, then the container filesystem is all good, how to get RUN commands to do run DOS commands in DOSEMU is probably more tricky.

Comment: If I was evil and replaced bash inside my Linux container with my own executable, would that be run each time Docker tried to run a command ?

Comment: OK, just discovered the SHELL command, which should let me change how commands are executed inside the container.